# Node Imap fetch children folder content

Tags: javascript, node.js, imap, inbox, node-imap

I didn't find any information about how retrieve email inside a children folder in my inbox using node-imap library.
This is my inbox structure :

```
INBOX
 CHILDREN
   CHILDREN2
```

I must retrieve all email in Children2. 
Thanks for your attention. I’m looking forward to your reply..

Comment: Just [get the list of mailboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30188940/fnord), find children2 in the result and open that mailbox.

Comment: Or if you know your server's separator, open that mailbox.  The separator is often / or . :` INBOX.CHILDREN.CHILDREN2`, `INBOX/CHILDREN/CHILDREN2`.  The LIST command will tell you which it is, and will also tell you folders are available.