# How to listen to all the inbound emails for an Email Server

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, imap

I need to create an email server which might have 1M emails.
I want to listen on all the email accounts basically listen for incoming emails(which would be around 20k each day)

I have the following node.js script which listens on **just one email.**
But I want to listen to all the **new emails for all the email accounts.**
How can I do that? Any ideas are welcome.
Or is there any other email server which provides that feature.

**My Objective is to be able to trigger an event whenever there is a new email on the server and save the attachment from that email.**

```
var MailListener = require("mail-listener4");
 
var mailListener = new MailListener({
  username: 'something@example.com',
  password: 'password',
  host: 'mail.example.com',
  port: 993, // imap port
  tls: true,
  connTimeout: 10000, // Default by node-imap
  authTimeout: 5000, // Default by node-imap,
  debug: console.log, // Or your custom function with only one incoming argument. Default: null
  tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
  mailbox: 'INBOX', // mailbox to monitor
  searchFilter: ["ALL"], // the search filter being used after an IDLE notification has been retrieved
  markSeen: true, // all fetched email willbe marked as seen and not fetched next time
  fetchUnreadOnStart: true, // use it only if you want to get all unread email on lib start. Default is `false`,
  mailParserOptions: {stream: true}, // options to be passed to mailParser lib.
  attachments: true, // download attachments as they are encountered to the project directory
  attachmentOptions: { directory: "attachments/" } ,
  searchFilter: ["UNSEEN"], 
  markSeen: true, // specify a download directory for attachments
});
 
mailListener.start(); 
 
mailListener.on("server:connected", function(){
  console.log("imapConnected");
});
 
mailListener.on("mailbox", function(mailbox){
  console.log("Total number of mails: ", mailbox.messages.total); // this field in mailbox gives the total number of emails
});
 
mailListener.on("server:disconnected", function(){
  console.log("imapDisconnected");
});
 
mailListener.on("error", function(err){
  console.log(err);
});
 
mailListener.on("mail", function(mail, seqno, attributes){
});
 
mailListener.on("attachment", function(attachment){
  console.log(attachment.path);
});
```

I can clarify more on my requirement if needed.

Comment: If you’re hosting the server, it would be way better to insert a script into the SMTP server.  Most unix style servers support putting “filters” or similar into the mail path, which would allow you to trigger something on every incoming email that goes through that server.  Trying to get them via IMAP is a losing battle.

Comment: Do you need to create an entire mail server just for your requirement or are you using some provider (gmail, hotmail, yahoo, yandex ) and just need to receive a kind of notification when a mail arrives to your user  inbox?

Comment: I need to create the entire email server as I have to assign an email account for each subscriber and then whenever there is a new email on any of the email we need to store it.

Answer (score 0):

supposing you're dealing with ideal conditions and you don't have to worry about performance, infrastructure, priviliges or anything you can do that by basically creating a connection for every account in that server and listening to that connection you can check this question to help you understand how to do that [How can i handle multiple imap connections in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905393/how-can-i-handle-multiple-imap-connections-in-node-js) and it's just basically that if you have access to a repertoire of accounts used by the mail server like an LDAP server or something like that you can just create an array of Connections that you can listen to individually:

```
  var Connection = []; 

  function connectImap(username, password, address, port, tls) {

   if (typeof Connection[username]             != typeof undefined &&
       typeof Connection[username].state       == typeof ''        &&
       Connection[username].state              == 'authenticated'  &&
       Connection[username]._config.user       == username         &&
       Connection[username]._config.password   == password) {

       console.log('IMAP-CLIENT-USE-AUTHENTICATED-CONNECTION ' + username);

   } else {

         port = port || 993;
         tls = tls || true;

      Connection[username] = new Imap({
            user        : username,
            password    : password,
            host        : address,
            port        : port,
            authTimeout : 10000,
            connTimeout : 10000,
            keepalive   : true,
            tls         : tls
           });

           console.log('IMAP-CLIENT-CONNECTED : ' + username);
    }
  }
```